# PHP DOM createElement - allow spaces

Tags: php, xml, dom

How to use spaces in createElement while creating xml file

I have to use

```
$main = $doc->createElement("$cname"."Data" );
```

where

```
$cname="Company Name"
```

But due to spaces in `$cname`, I am getting the following error,

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception
>   'DOMException' with message 'Invalid
>   Character Error' in file.php:50 Stack
>   trace: #0 file.php(50):
>   DOMDocument->createElement('geosoft
>   company...') #1 {main} thrown in
>   file.php on line 50

How to rectify this?

Regards,
Rekha

Comment: Have you every seen an XML document that contains elements like `<name morename>...` ? ;) So you have to "remove" the space...

Answer (score 5):

According to http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/#NT-NameChar an element name can only consists of the following characters

> NameStartChar      ::=      ":" | [A-Z] | "_" | [a-z] | [#xC0-#xD6] | [#xD8-#xF6] | [#xF8-#x2FF] | [#x370-#x37D] | [#x37F-#x1FFF] | [#x200C-#x200D] | [#x2070-#x218F] | [#x2C00-#x2FEF] | [#x3001-#xD7FF] | [#xF900-#xFDCF] | [#xFDF0-#xFFFD] | [#x10000-#xEFFFF]
>
> NameChar       ::=       NameStartChar | "-" | "." | [0-9] | #xB7 | [#x0300-#x036F] | [#x203F-#x2040]

possible alternative:

```
$main = $doc->createElement("Data");
$main->setAttribute('origin', $cname);
```

you might also be interested in [xml namespaces](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml-names/)